# Property of distributional derivative.

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory

There is a common result that if a function $f$ is locally integrable then there is a condition for the distribution derivative $f'$ to be a complex measure. One of them is that $f$ agrees a.e. with a function of bounded variation $F$. And if so, we have $\langle f',\phi\rangle=\int\varphi dF$. Was looking for a reference for this proof. (And why this fails as a necessary condition)

EDIT: Thanks to @reuns, it is easy to see why it is not necessary. Does strengthening to bounded variation with $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} f(x)=0$ do the trick?

Comment: I'd say $\Re(f)=g+h$ with $g$ of bounded variation (giving a finite measure) and $h$ increasing or decreasing (giving a non-signed measure)

Comment: Ah yes! that is easy. I suppose strengthening to $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ should make it necessary?

Comment: Is this in one dimension, with BV defined using the total variation norm? If so it is discussed in Folland's Real Analysis text (section 3.5) for instance.